# Asp net MVC 5 and listbox with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

After several days of reading on how to fill a listbox with linq i am completely lost on what I have to do to make this work. I know I have to have a viewmodel or something like that but since i cannot reference 2 models in the same view I don t know what to do.

this is the model i have

```
public class ABC
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public class  ABCDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ABC> ABCs { get; set; }
    }
}

public class ABCModel
{
    public string type{ set; get; }
    public List<ABC> ABCs { set; get; }
}
```

The controller i know i am missing a lot of things but I don´t know how to fill the list with that linq query nor how to call this controller from the view without using beginform (I will have more than 1 listbox in this form )

```
public ActionResult GetStuff()
    {

       var Types = from m in db.ABCs
                   select m.Type.Distinct();

        return View(Types); 
    }
```

And then on my view i am required to have 
@model IEnumerable so i can show on that page everything that the table abc has.

So, can I create a viewModel that fills the lsitbox (I will need to fill at least 6 with the parameters that abc has so the user can search for abcs with those values, but i suppose that if i can understand how to do 1 i can do it for 6) with what I want and that allows me to show the entries that abc has?

and this is the view ( i know a lot of things are wrong with it but its just to give an example)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("getSelectedValues", "ABC", FormMethod.Get))
{
    Type:@Html.DropDownList() 

    a:@Html.DropDownList()

    b:@Html.DropDownList()

    //and so on

    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
```

Pardon for my ignorance for any aspect i missed but i am new to asp net mvc 5, also if anyone could just guide me or send me a guide on what I have to do i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should use a view model to represent what you want to display and edit but its not clear what it is that you actually editing and what properties you want to display dropownlists for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is you create a ViewModel named MYPAGENAMEViewModel.cs, then in that ViewModel you have all the 'model' / data that you need for the view.cshtml file.... i.e. something like the following:

```
public class MYPAGENAMEViewModel
{
    public List<Types> MyTypes { get; set; }
    public List<OtherTypes> MyOtherTypes { get; set; }
}
```

then in your action.

```
public ActionResult GetStuff()
{
   MYPAGENAMEViewModel myViewModel = new MYPAGENAMEViewModel();

   myViewModel.MyTypes = from m in db.ABCs
                       select m.Type.Distinct();

   myViewModel.MyOtherTypes = from m in db.CBAs
                              select m.Type.Distinct();

   return View(myViewModel); 
}
```

then at the top of your view:

```
@model MYPAGENAMEViewModel
```

and then later in the view:

```
MyTypes<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyTypes.TypeId, (SelectList)model.MyTypes.TypeName) 

MyOtherTypes<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyOtherTypes.TypeId, (SelectList)model.MyOtherTypes.TypeName)
```

Comment: i am getting an "Cannot implicitly convert type  System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>> to 'project.Models.ViewModel". I have tried some conversions but none seem to work.  And is there anyway to have both model ViewModel and model ABC in the view?

Comment: @Donvan What information are you trying to convert? IEnumerable<char> is never going to go directly into ViewModel, also IQueryable means you are trying in essence to put the query itself into the view model (look into Lazy Loading to understand that part a bit better), first execute the query with something like .ToList()... You could pass ABC explicitly in the HttpContext.Session, but you should really pass ABC as a property of the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I managed to achieve what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're after but this might be the solution.

First off, you'd create a ViewModel, such as:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
 List<ABC> abcs { get; set; } // Your database values that you're going to loop through
 List<WhateverALookupShouldBe> aDropDownValues { get; set; }
 List<WhateverBLookupShouldBe> bDropDownValues { get; set; }
 // etc
 }
```

Populate those values in your Data or Controller.

If you're looping through a list and submitting values back you'll want an editor for, so make a folder under your view folder called "EditorTemplates". Then add a cshtml file with the same name as your model, e.g. ABC.

On your main view you would have:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.abcs)
```

Now in your ABC Editor template you would write something like this for your drop down lists:

```
@model ABC

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.a, new SelectList(Model.aDropDownValues, "DataValueFieldName", "DataTextFieldName"));
```

When you submit it back you should have the data returned to you.